# Return path from depth-first search

Tags: c#, search, depth-first-search

I'm trying to find a specific node in the graph by depth-first search. My current (simple) implementation is working, but only returns a `bool`, i.e. whether the node has been found.

I'd like to add functionality to return a path from the operation, so for example if I search for `5` in following example, I will get `"1-2-3-5"` instead of only `true`.

[image]

```
public class BinaryTreeNode
{
    public List<BinaryTreeNode> Children { get; set; }
    public int Data { get; set; }
}
public class DepthFirstSearch
{
    private Stack _searchStack;
    private BinaryTreeNode _root;
    public DepthFirstSearch(BinaryTreeNode rootNode)
    {
        _root = rootNode;
        _searchStack = new Stack();
    }
    public bool Search(int data)
    {
        BinaryTreeNode _current;
        _searchStack.Push(_root);
        while (_searchStack.Count != 0)
        {
            _current = _searchStack.Pop();
            if (_current.Data == data)
            {
                return true;
            }

            foreach(BinaryTreeNode b in current.Children.AsEnumerable().Reverse())
                _searchStack.Push(b);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what does it return if it is not found?

Comment: @Hogan In that case, an empty string or anything like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another way to do it. 
This approach stores parent information on each node and `getPath` walk up the tree and return values. But your tree is not a binary tree maybe you should change the class name to just TreeNode or something.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var root = createNode();
    var search = new DepthFirstSearch(root);
    var result = search.Search(5);
    var arr = result.getPath();
    arr.Reverse();
    Console.Write(String.Join("-",arr));
}
public class DepthFirstSearch
{
    private Stack _searchStack;
    private BinaryTreeNode _root;
    public DepthFirstSearch(BinaryTreeNode rootNode)
    {
        _root = rootNode;
        _searchStack = new Stack();
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode Search(int data)
    {
        BinaryTreeNode _current;
        _searchStack.Push(_root);
        while (_searchStack.Count != 0)
        {
            _current = (BinaryTreeNode)_searchStack.Pop();
            if (_current.Data == data)
            {
                return _current;
            }

            foreach (BinaryTreeNode b in _current.Children.AsEnumerable().Reverse())
                _searchStack.Push(b);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class BinaryTreeNode
{
    public BinaryTreeNode parent { get; set; }
    public List<BinaryTreeNode> Children { get; set; }
    public int Data { get; set; }

    public List<int> getPath()
    {
        var list = new List<int>(){Data};

        if (parent != null)
        {
            list.AddRange(parent.getPath());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to store a `BinaryTreeNode Parent { get; set; }` in your `BinaryTreeNode` class, which is `null` if there is no parent and otherwise it's the parent of the node. These would be set up when you construct your tree initially. Then you can simply return the node that was found (or `null` if nothing was found) and go through the parents to reconstruct the list with something like

```
List<int> path = new List<int>();
BinaryTreeNode found = new DepthFirstSearch(root).Search();
while(found != null)
{
    path.Push(found.Data);
    found = found.Parent;
}
string stringPath = String.Join("-", path);
```

I don't remember exactly the semantics of `Push` so you might end up having to reverse the list or append to the end of the list or something like that instead of using `Push`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the example in the tree image is not a binary tree node because the first node (the root) has 3 children. Binary trees are supposed to have nodes with only two child nodes, one called "left" and the other "right", hence the "bi" in "binary tree"

Also, your implementation of the BinaryTreeNode has 2 good ideas:

1. A value called "Data" (You're correct that a node needs to store this "data"). But I would suggest **not** naming your variable "Data" because there are other variables and libraries in C# with the word "Data" in them. How about naming it "nodeData"? The more descriptive and unique, the better.
2. You have the right idea in storing the children, but a **List** of other BinaryTreeNodes is incorrect, because what if that list accidentally has more than 2 children? Again, you can do this if you want, but then this will be a "tree", not a "binary tree" data structure. How about instead of:

   ```
   public List<BinaryTreeNode> Children { get; set; }
   ```

do

```
public BinaryTreeNode LeftNode { get; set; }
public BinaryTreeNode RightNode { get; set; }
```

Now your "bool Search" function:

You are pushing all the children of a node into a stack. By definition, this would almost be a "breadth first search" not a "depth first search". "Breadth" because you are storing nodes by "rows" (or "breadth") first. Think row 0 being the root node, row 1 being the children of root, row 2 being the children of the children of root,... and so on. The fact that you use a stack means you're going to search the last child node that was popped into the stack _searchStack. A correct breadth-first uses a queue rather than a stack (FIFO vs FILO), but that's out of the scope of this question.

Your depth-first search should focus on saving one (and only one) node at a time. For that first root node, you choose ONE child. Then you call a depth-first search on that ONE child. That child will choose one of it's children, and call depth-first on that. And so on. If a node doesn't have children, you return/exit the function. After a node has finished with one child, call the depth-first search on the other child. The general idea of depth-first search is that you want to go "deep" into the tree before you cover any of the sibling nodes.

**To answer your question:**

Once you implement DFS successfully, you need to find a way to "remember" which parent nodes you already traversed through and build a string from the found child node up towards the parent node as you go back out of the "depth".

So in your example, *after* DFS finds "5" down the tree, it would then go up the tree:
5
3-5
2-3-5
1-2-3-5